# sql - result decimal precision and scale when calculating average

Tags: sql, decimal, average, scale, precision

If i have a column with datatype decimal(p,s) what is the standard for expected  result's precision and scale when i execute average aggregate.? 
i.e *result = select avg(decimal(p,s)) from table1;*
what is must be the result decimal precision and scale.?

Some links from existing databases like 
1. https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqlj36146.html#rrefsqlj36146
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/avg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

But unable to see any standard followed here. So is there a well accepted standard of this in sql or is it always implementation basis.?

Comment: If there is a standard, it is not worth remembering.  Just cast the value to the scale and precision that you want after you take the average.  I once tried to follow the rules in SQL Server, and just decided that it is not worth the effort to fully understand.

Answer (score 0):

Personally not aware of a standard, have always adjusted based on the level of detail that is required of the column.

Comment: when the query do not contain any expected level of detail, what is best justified result precision and scale.?

Comment: My personal default is 18,4 but I have been conditioned by my environment